# Script that reads each file separately

Tags: powershell

I have a folder and within that folder it has .txt files with fax numbers as part of the file name (the first 10 characters contain the fax number).

I am trying to write a script that would read each file name for the fax number then writes it into a "control file".

However, it **cannot put all the fax numbers at one time** into the Control file. I need it to read the fax number of file 1 and write it into the control file, then move onto file 2, read the fax number and overwrite the control file with the fax number of file 2. And so on and so forth.

The script I have so far reads the fax numbers and writes to the control file, but it reads all the fax numbers and adds each one to the control file. I need it to write one by one.

This is what I have so far:

```
$directory = "C:\Users\blah\Desktop\TestFolder"
$controlfile = "C:\Users\blah\Desktop\Scripts\control.txt"

$filename = Get-ChildItem -path $directory -name -filter *.txt 
foreach($file in $directory)
{
    $faxnumber = $filename.substring(0,10) 
    Set-Content $controlfile "<tofaxnum:$faxnumber>
<toname:XXX>
<tocompany:XXX>
<fromname: XXX>
<fromphone:XXX>" -force
}
```

So if there are 3 files in `$directory` it writes all 3 fax numbers into the control file as opposed to looking at the first file then writing, then moving onto the 2nd file then writing, then onto the 3rd. Any help or ideas you can provide would be very much appreciated.

Comment: may I ask you why you don't want to write all fax numbers at once?

Comment: The control file is used by another process to send a fax. If the control file contains more than 1 fax number the fax will not send.

Comment: ah okay, that make sense.

Answer (score 2):

You have to *iterate over each filename* returned from the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet instead of using the *filenames* within the loop:

```
$directory = "C:\Users\blah\Desktop\TestFolder"
$controlfile = "C:\Users\blah\Desktop\Scripts\control.txt"

$filenames = Get-ChildItem -path $directory -name -filter *.txt 
foreach($filename in $filenames)
{
    $faxnumber = $filename.substring(0,10) 
    Set-Content $controlfile "<tofaxnum:$faxnumber>
<toname:XXX>
<tocompany:XXX>
<fromname: XXX>
<fromphone:XXX>" -force
}
```

Comment: Nice catch, Martin.  I completely missed that oversight.

Comment: I am very new to this, are you able to explain this to me the same way you would explain it to a complete idiot?

Comment: You stored the result of the `Get-ChildItem` cmdlet into `$filename`. So `$filename` is a **list** of filenames but not a single filename. So I changed the variable to `$filenames` and put it into your `foreach` loop to *iterate* over each filename. So in each iteration the current filename is stored into `$filename` ...

Comment: Ohhhhh I see. Thank you very much. Seriously a very big help.

Comment: One more question, if I wanted to have the file moved or deleted after the control file was written, how would the syntax go?

Comment: Add `Remove-Item (Join-Path $directory $filename) -force` within the foreach loop. Please consider to accept the answer.